# Memory Division in C

Tags: c, memory, stack

I'm trying to understand the division of the memory. I know that it's divided in stack, heap, globals and constants. The stack contains the variables inside the `main ()`, the heap it's used with the `malloc` function; but which is the difference between globals and constants? I hope you can help me to solve this doubt. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [where pointers and global variables in C are saved in memory, in heap or in stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113668/where-pointers-and-global-variables-in-c-are-saved-in-memory-in-heap-or-in-stac)

Comment: It is operating system and/or processor and/or compiler specific (i.e. implementation). I'm not sure the C standard *requires* a stack (even if every implementation of C I know about uses one)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: C Standard does not require stack. In general it does not tell how things are or should be implemented internally (See C11 1/p2 Scope). It just happens that is used commonly for storing objects with automatic storage duration, mostly by the architecture of CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants may be inlined by the compiler so that they are not backed by a memory location at all. Constants that are backed by a memory location may be put in readonly memory. The exact implementation depends on the compiler, the OS and hardware. For example, on a modern computer with a modern OS constants may be placed in virtual memory pages marked as read-only. An attempt to write to such memory will generate a general protection fault. On an embedded system, constants may be placed in ROM.

Literal strings that you use in your program are commonly assigned into constant memory.

None of this is required by the C standard. The only thing required of a portable program is that you do not attempt to modify your constants. If you modify data that the compiler thinks is constant, your program's behavior is undefined. Consider, for example, what happens if you take a an address of a string literal used in your program and try to modify the string through this pointer. The same string may be used elsewhere in your program and the compiler is allowed to merge all occurrences and only allocate space for one copy of the string. On some implementations you may be able to modify the string, which will affect all parts of your program that happen to use the same string literal. On other implementations you'll get a general protection fault and your program will terminate. On still other implementations you will modify your string as if it was not constant.