# Where the Pointer variables are stored and how compiler access normal variable?

Tags: c

I got little Confused about pointer variable storage location can anyone please help me.

```
int *ptr; //where this pointer stored
int p; //how compiler can access this variable(using address or what?)
```

pointers are accessed by address what about normal variable...?

please suggest me to best website to learn C...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location of pointers and global variables in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113668/location-of-pointers-and-global-variables-in-c)

Comment: In short *a pointer is a normal variable that holds an address to something else as its value* while *a variable is a label to a memory address that holds a direct value*. You derefernce a pointer to obtain the direct value at the address held by the pointer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the scope of the information requested is easily found both here, and in any C manual or tutorial.

Comment: It depends on your system. The standard doesn't specify such things.

Comment: To understand that,  learn basic assembly programming if you haven't, compile your program as `gcc -Wall -save-temps src.c -o src`, and see for yourself in the file `src.s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. where this pointer stored?

A pointer is stored just like any other normal variable in the memory. Where exactly depends on whether it is a local variable, in which case it is stored in the stack, or a global or static variable, in which case it is stored in a separate memory section for globals.

2. how compiler can access this variable?

Not sure what you mean by compiler access here, but you as a programmer can access the variable directly, you can store the address in a pointer and then access it indirectly.

```
a = p; //Direct access

int *ptr;
ptr = &p;
a = *ptr;   // Access the variable indirectly.
```

As for your third question recommending a website, it is outside the scope of StackOverflow.