# Why is this program giving a stack overflow?

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

My C merge code works when I initialize the array globally at the top of the program until the stack overflows.  I'm trying to initialize the array with [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), but when I do, the code will only read in two integers and stop running.

This program pulls random numbers from a file called alg.txt and then sorts them. Again, the code works (up until 500k integers) when defining z at the top of the program to the number of integers to be sorted, and declaring the array globally to be equal to arr[z]. How do I figure out what is going on?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count = 0;
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
        count++;

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];
        count++;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            count++;
        }
        k++;
        count++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
        count++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
        count++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("alg.txt", "r");

    int z;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(z*sizeof(int));
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(i=0; i < z; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &arr[i]);
    }

    mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);

    printf("\nSorted array is \n");
    printArray(arr, n);
    printf("count is %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` is `int n = sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int);`

Comment: `int L[n1], R[n2];` They consume stacks on every call. An array that is too large can not be secured.

Comment: C is not the same as C++ (so the C++ tag is wrong)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then **use the debugger** `gdb` to understand what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring the **L** and **R** array's locally (inside the `merge` function). They consume stack on every function call. You should initialize them globally so that they can be stored on the heap. Also, you should declare just one array (like **temp_arr** in the below code) as there's no need for two separate arrays like **L** and **R**.

See [Local vs Global variable storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113668/location-of-pointers-and-global-variables-in-c)

You can improve your merge function to this:

```
int temp_arr[500000];   // Global declaration
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i=l, j=m+1, k=l;
    while(i<=m && j<=r)
    {
        if(arr[i]<arr[j])
            temp_arr[++k] = arr[++i];
        else temp_arr[++k] = arr[++j];
    }
    while(i<=m)
        temp_arr[++k] = arr[++i];
    while(j<=r)
        temp_arr[++k] = arr[++j];
    i = l;
    while(i<=r)
        arr[i] = temp_arr[++i];  // Storing stored array in arr
}
```

Comment: That code won't even compile. You cannot initialize a global variable with a `malloc` expression (outside of any routine) and you should not cast the result of `malloc` in C.